# Why does MATLAB native function cov (covariance matrix computation) use a different divisor than I expect?

Tags: matlab, covariance

Given a data matrix data of M dimensions and N samples, say,

```
data = randn(N, M);
```

I could compute the covariance matrix with

```
data_mu = data - ones(N, 1)*mean(data);
cov_matrix = (data_mu'*data_mu)./N
```

If I use the native MATLAB function

```
cov_matrix2 = cov(data)
```

this will always be equal to

```
cov_matrix = (data_mu'*data_mu)./(N-1)
```

That is, the denominator is (N - 1) is one less.

Why?? Can you reproduce it? Is this a bug??

I use MATLAB version 7.6.0.324 (2008).

Comment: No way Matlab would let a "bug" like that slip by them. There is a reason for `N-1`, let me find it. http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/newton/askasci/1993/math/MATH014.HTM http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_the_standard_deviation_calculation_for_populations_different_than_for_samples_and_why_is_the_denominator_'n'_or_'n-1'

Comment: It probably depends on whether you're looking at `sample (co)variance` or `population (co)variance`. For large N they are pretty close, but you have to be careful with small N.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> That is, the denominator is (N - 1) is one less.
>   Why?? Can you reproduce it? Is this a bug??

See the [cov documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cov.html). It has to do with [population variance vs. sample variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance).

Note also that if you wish to use the denominator N instead of N-1, you can add a trailing `1` argument to the call, i.e. `cov(x,y,1)` or `cov(x,1)` as per the documentation.

Comment: ha, I obviously can't read. I did 'help cov' before posting this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

n-1 is the correct denominator to use in computation of variance.
It is what's known as Bessel's correction (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction)
Simply put, 1/(n-1) produces a more accurate expected estimate of the variance than 1/n.