# cov(A,1) equivalent in R

Tags: r, matlab

in the matlab documentation [there](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html) function `cov(A,1)`,where `A` is a matrix, is used to compute the covariance normalized by the number of rows. what is the equivalent of `cov(A,1)` in R? thank you.

Comment: divide by the number of rows after calculating cov? `ans <- cov(A); ans / nrow(ans)`

Comment: could you define what it means to normalize by the number of rows?

Comment: @chinsoon12 it's not that. it give different result with the one in matlab

Comment: @TUSHAr as stated in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/cov.html) cov(X, 1) or cov(X, Y, 1) normalizes by N and produces the second moment matrix of the observations about their mean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

apparently,

`A = A-matrix(1,T,1) %*% colMeans(A)
covmat = Conj(t(A))%*%A/T`

where T is number of rows will give the same output with matlab `cov(A,1)`, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cov(A)`. Don't complicate things. A co-variance matrix is automatically normalised by the number of records

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still need the `cov(A,1)` to match the output of some function in matlab and R. and i've got the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256798/why-does-matlab-native-function-cov-covariance-matrix-computation-use-a-differ?rq=1